# How to start a countdown by clicking on a touchableOpacity in react native?

Tags: function, react-native, countdowntimer, touchableopacity, onpress

How do I start a `<CountDown/>`  when a `TouchableOpacity` is pressed?

I recently discovered the countdown component of react-native.

The countdown starts automatically, but I want it to start running when I click on a `TouchableOpacity`. How can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very basic example which helps you

```
constructor(props: Object) {
  super(props);
  this.state ={ timer: 3}
}

componentDidUpdate(){
  if(this.state.timer === 1){ 
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
}

componentWillUnmount(){
 clearInterval(this.interval);
}

startTimer(){
  this.interval = setInterval(
    () => this.setState((prevState)=> ({ timer: prevState.timer - 1 })),
    1000
  );
}

render() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', }}>
      <Text> {this.state.timer} </Text>
      <Button title="Start" onPress={() => this.startTimer() } />
    </View> 
  )
}
```